# Can permanent magnets be exploited to create energy?

Tags: energy

There are many videos on youtube in which permanent magnets are used to make a motor. Although it might be possible in an ideal environment (e.g. no friction). As these devices are rotating continously means that they are producing energy to overcome friction and other energy losses.

Is it really possible to produce energy only using permanent magnets (without using other energy source other than initial force as shown in videos)

Some videos:

1. [Free Energy Magnet Motor (Engine)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7PDeK6rprA4)
2. [Xpenzif free energy screw magnet motor](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dT9s33X9D4I)
3. [Steorn concept Permanent Magnet Moter Test](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yei0NMqUaZ8)
4. [Free energy 1 magnet disk](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5DvPLFX5gwA)
5. <strike>[Removed video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i0oUaPZ_wF8)</strike>
6. [Screw Magnet Motor](http://peswiki.com/index.php/OS:Screw-Magnet_Motor)
7. [perpetual motion machine selfrunning](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aHVBu77jz4w)

   - [Can magnets rotate infinitely?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/2167/847)  (I was suggested to ask it here as well)

Comment: Constant motion in an ideal environment is not energy generation.

Comment: If I understand the concept correctly, there are two ways in which that process can be implemented, but, according to Pieter B, "**constant motion in an ideal environment is not energy generation**."

Comment: It is totally possible as long as you don't mind being arrested for breaking the second law of thermodynamics. :-)

Comment: @matt_black - is that really a felony, or will it only get you a ticket? After all, you CAN break the law as long as you do so in an open system.

Comment: @woodchips If the question were about an open system, he would be asking whether electrical generators existed.

Comment: Check out this link (http://peswiki.com/energy/Directory%3aMagnet_Motors) for various similar projects tried

Comment: @woodchips - the second law applies to a closed system, so saying you can break it in an open system is like saying you can break the 25 mph speed limit if you're in a 65 mph zone - it really doesn't mean anything.

Comment: @Mark - I find myself truly amazed that you can't recognize an attempt at humor. You honestly felt it necessary to state the obvious, and to do so 5 months after the fact?

Comment: Sorry Woodchips.  I guess I thought we shouldn't make assumptions about what is or isn't obvious when responding to a question about perpetual motion.  As for taking 5 months to respond, just call me a slow reader!

Comment: @PieterB Environment in example videos is no where close to ideal.

Answer (score 24):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perpetual_motion) explains:

> There is a scientific consensus that perpetual motion in an isolated system violates either the first law of thermodynamics, the second law of thermodynamics, or both.

There is a [long history](http://journals.cambridge.org/action/displayAbstract;jsessionid=236AD2358A2C122EACC5E6B0F6D28BAF.journals?fromPage=online&aid=2943792) of different types of failed perpetual motion machines - enough for [books to be written](http://books.google.com.au/books?id=022yYXnS_GQC&lpg=PA9&ots=0DNyNC9VY6&dq=perpetual%20motion&lr&pg=PA15#v=onepage&q=perpetual%20motion&f=false).

Kevin Kilty has written a [more readable discussion](http://www.kilty.com/pmotion.htm) on the types of perpetual motion machine, and provides a categorisation of the types of false claims that they make.

A very quick review of the list of videos, and we are able to categorise them.

1. Free Energy Magnet Motor (Engine): Category 5 = Fraud

   The claim is that the electromagnets in a simple electric motor were replaced by permanent magnets, requiring no external power.

   It only takes primary-school science to understand this is a fake. [Electric motors](http://electronics.howstuffworks.com/motor.htm) require the polarity of the magnetism to change as the axle turns. A permanent magnet would simple freeze the axle in place.

   I speculate a hidden battery, although I also considered an electromagnet hidden behind the carpet.
2. Xpenzif free energy screw magnet motor: Category 6 - Perpetually Out Of Balance

   This design will not work. The magnets will not pull the next screw-head forward, as it would be dragged back by the other magnet closest to a screw-head.

   The video shown would be easily faked, as the base of the axle was not shown.
3. Steorn concept Permanent Magnet Moter Test: Category 8 - Machines without losses or friction

   Only a prototype, which was not an isolated system, was shown. The device is manually powered.

   This design will not work. What is shown is a prototype where the builder is underestimating how much energy he is putting into the system. The system will not generate enough energy (due to friction and conversion loss) to continually power itself when he eventually does close the cycle.
4. Free energy 1 magnet disk

   There is insufficient detail shown to understand what the claim is here.
5. Removed video
6. Screw Magnet Motor - Already covered under #2 above.
7. perpetual motion machine selfrunning: Category 4: Long running machine?

   There isn't enough detail here to be sure, but it looks like merely a long running machine, that will eventually wind down. Note that it makes a considerable noise, so it fails to be a machine "without losses or friction" - the sound energy being lost is evidence of that.

Comment: I was very interested in last device because it was very similar to the device that I made in my mind. If it is moving continuously and producing sound as well then it is producing energy. Although you have answered in detail, I am collecting magnets to do my own experiments and understand the flaws.

Comment: *claps* - well done Oddthinking!

Comment: My father have two washer-shaped magnets inserted in a vertical rod, the support base of the rod is also a magnet and it's flat. They are put in a way that magnets repel each other. Well, the two magnets at the top have been levitating for years. Isn't there a source of energy there preventing the magnets to fall for years without being exhausted?

Comment: @user1598390: Nope. There isn't. This is high school physics. No work is being done. No energy is being used up (converted). That's not a machine.

Comment: Isn't keeping an object from falling without touching it work?

Comment: @user1598390: No, by definition.

Answer (score 4):

The old dream of a Perpetual motion, will never come true.

[Reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perpetual_motion)

> A more obscure category is a perpetual motion machine of the third
>   kind, usually (but not always)[5] defined as one that completely
>   eliminates friction and other dissipative forces, to maintain motion
>   forever (due to its mass inertia). Third in this case refers solely to
>   the position in the above classification scheme, not the third law of
>   thermodynamics. Although it is impossible to make such a
>   machine,[6][7] as dissipation can never be 100% eliminated in a
>   mechanical system, it is nevertheless possible to get very close to
>   this ideal (see examples in the Low Friction section). Such a machine
>   would not serve as a source of energy but would have utility as a
>   perpetual energy storage device.
>
> Use of the term "impossible" and perpetual motion
>   The seemingly mysterious ability of magnets to influence motion at a
>   distance without any apparent energy source has long appealed to
>   inventors. One of the earliest examples of a magnetic motor was
>   proposed by Wilkins and has been widely copied since: it consists of a
>   ramp with a magnet at the top, which pulled a metal ball up the ramp.
>   Near the magnet was a small hole that was supposed to allow the ball
>   to drop under the ramp and return to the bottom, where a flap allowed
>   it to return to the top again. The device simply could not work: any
>   magnet strong enough to pull the ball up the ramp would necessarily be
>   too powerful to allow it to drop through the hole. Faced with this
>   problem, more modern versions typically use a series of ramps and
>   magnets, positioned so the ball is to be handed off from one magnet to
>   another as it moves. The problem remains the same.

Comment: Never is a pretty long timespan ;) ... still +1 and greetings to all Delphians out there *g*