# Has Reidar Finsrud created a perpetual motion machine?

Tags: physics, perpetual-motion

I found some websites claiming a Norwegian artist (Reidar Finsrud) created a true perpetual motion machine. Perpetual motion is a concept that would violate both the first and second thermodynamics' laws.

Here is a [YouTube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KD3yft0XKIw) showing the machine:

Is this a perpetual motion machine?

Comment: it looks like a low-friction ball track with lots of bells and whistles more than anything else.

Comment: If it really worked, he wouldn't be stopping it with his hand all the time.

Comment: Aren't 30 seconds considerably shorter than eternity?

Answer (score 18):

As discussed in my answer to a strongly-related question - [Can permanent magnets be exploited to create energy?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/14283/can-permanent-magnets-be-exploited-to-create-energy/14295#14295) - there have been so many attempts to create perpetual motion machines like this one, that Adjunct Engineering professor, Dr. Kevin Kilty, has written an [essay that provides categories](http://www.kilty.com/pmotion.htm) and explains how they inevitably fail to be true Perpetual Motion machines.

Finsrud's contraption belongs in category 8: "Machines without losses or friction".

The [Laws of Thermodynamics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laws_of_thermodynamics) have been well-tested and verified in a wide-range of situations. A video showing a demonstration of a perpetual motion machine running for 30 seconds is insufficient evidence to overturn our acceptance of them.